# Bad implementation issue with Admob interstitial - late upload - timeless interstitial

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I have a big problem with admob interstitial adds. Ads openinig delay and user clickin invalid. Lots of invalid click occurs. This is bad user experience can be suspend my AdMob account. How can I get rid of this bad situation.

I want it to work [like this][1]

**My code:**

```
onCreate method;

interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(REKLAM_ID);

AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
});
```

So What is the best way for interstitial use?

My app has a few page and when I add in anyone it open timeless specially delay open when user press any button.

I want to start when app loading is this code true?

Comment: Your "I want it to work like this" link is broken. You want it to work like what?

Comment: The link about : App launch / Interstitial shows  / Content loaded...   Am I make Interstitial app launching.  When user press app icon on the home screen,  app starts and interstitial shows than content shows.    bu when I try this It show timeless and user click any buttons unwanted clicks.  I really want to solve but just try to learn more.  Thanks

Comment: Just saying that the link doesn't work. If you want to add further info to the question, it's better to edit the question itself than to provide that info in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to decide which is the best time to show the admob ad. 
You can check the admob best practices for interstitial [Interstitial best practice](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=en)

After that you need to separate the ad loading to the ad presentation in order to avoid ad display on unwanted time

first load the ad:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this); 
interstitial.setAdUnitId(REKLAM_ID);
AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);
```

When you want to display the ad - check for availability and display if its loaded:

```
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
```

That way the ad will display immediately without delay

Comment: And don't call interstitial.show() from onAdLoaded().